# please give me some solution to this error Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

```
func doGetLocalDataUser() -> logInResponse {
     var localData : logInResponse? = nil
     if let userData = UserDefaults.standard
                                    .data(forKey: ConstantStrings.KEY_USER_LOGIN_DATA),let user = try? JSONDecoder()
                                    .decode(logInResponse.self ,from: userData){
                                            localData = user
                                    }
        return localData!
    }
```

Comment: if logInResponse != nil then if UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: ConstantStrings.KEY_USER_LOGIN_DATA) != nil maybe...anyway, start learning to think before code. No rude, just a clear advice. Play with guard for safe. You tell in code localData is optional, then you return as !

Comment: You didn't even bother to paste the error in Google, because there's like 10 different links to SO with answers to that question

Answer (score 0):

`localData` is nil, so you are force unwrapping `localData` (as a `logInResponse`) illegally.

If your optional chaining finds `nil` at any point (for example your `userData` doesn't exist in `UserDefaults` / has the wrong type) then it won't execute.

You are declaring this `doGetLocalDataUser()` function to return a non optional `logInResponse` type and force unwrapping a `nil` value to try and retrieve one. Best practice is to avoid the force unwrap "bang" operator "`!`" because it can lead to fatal errors like this.

Simple solution is to change your method to return an optional `logInResponse?` type, and eliminate the bang operator:

```
func doGetLocalDataUser() -> logInResponse? {
    if let userData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: ConstantStrings.KEY_USER_LOGIN_DATA), let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(logInResponse.self ,from: userData){
        return user
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would change the method to this:

```
func doGetLocalDataUser() -> logInResponse? {
    guard let userData = UserDefaults.standard.data(forKey: ConstantStrings.KEY_USER_LOGIN_DATA), let user = try? JSONDecoder().decode(logInResponse.self ,from: userData) else {
        return nil
    }

    return user
}
```

Keep in mind JSON decoding can fail (maybe has wrong format), therefore user will be nil, and this method can return nil